# Show help for command from within Django management command

Tags: python, django

I want to show the output of `manage.py <command> help` if there are not enough meaningful args to execute the command.

My code looks like:

```py
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Command, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument(
            'args', metavar='item', nargs='+',
            help="item = 'users'|'data'|..."
        )

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        items = [x.lower() for x in set(args)]
        if not items:
            call_command('startapp', '--help')
```

`call_command()` seems like an expensive way to call help. Is there a method that I can call on `self` that will do the same thing? The output without the `call_command()` looks like this...

```
$ python manage.py startapp
usage: manage.py startapp [-h] [--version] [-v {0,1,2,3}]
                          [--settings SETTINGS] [--pythonpath PYTHONPATH]
                          [--traceback] [--no-color] [--force-color]
                          item [item ...]
manage.py startapp: error: the following arguments are required: item
```

I'd prefer it to show the full output of `manage.py startapp --help` and not show

```
manage.py startapp: error: the following arguments are required: item
```

Comment: Use `nargs='+'` if there should be at least one

Comment: Good point. And I made the change. It returns a `manage.py startapp: error: the following arguments are required: item` as opposed to the output of `manage.py startapp --help`. Original question still stands.

Comment: Does defining [`missing_args_message`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/#django.core.management.BaseCommand.missing_args_message) change the output?

Comment: No. It customizes the error message; it isn't obvious how to skip the error message completely and redirect to `--help`.

Comment: Upon further reflection, the best reason to use `nargs='*'` instead of `nargs='+'` is to avoid the error message and use `call_command()` as I was doing earlier. I know it is kludgy, and maybe I'm missing something, or not doing it the right way by doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `self.print_help` method. For example:

```
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        items = [x.lower() for x in set(args)]
        if not items:
            self.print_help('manage.py', '<your command name>')
            sys.exit(1)
```